# How can I get ORACLE CONTAINS to match the literal word 'NOT'

Tags: oracle, contains

Why does this

```
SELECT * FROM clinical_trials
WHERE CONTAINS(study_title, '%Not%') > 0
```

not match:
'Not Available'

Comment: CONTAINS() is specific to columns indexed with ORACLE TEXT. If your table is not indexed in that fashion, then use SELECT * FROM clinical_trials where study_title LIKE '%Not%';

Comment: or `INSTR(study_title,'Not') > 0`

Answer (score 3):

Check the stop list you use for the text index. The default - `DEFAULT_STOPLIST` - includes 'not' so this word is not indexed by default.

You can see the defined stop lists and their content using

`SELECT * FROM ctxsys.ctx_stopwords;`

and

`SELECT * FROM ctxsys.ctx_stoplists;`